# Are there significant problems with the AMD FX Bulldozer processors?

Tags: cpu

I'm considering buying one, because of the great price.

Though the advertised specs and features are enough to more than justify the price, some reviews and benchmarks I've read have a very 'mixed' feel about it.

I'll use it for programming and and some heavy tasks on a Linux system, apart from being a home file server, so the argument about 'regular software doesn't utilize threads' is not valid for my case.

So, my question to those who use it, have you observed any noticeable problem with it ?

Apart from that, I'd be happy with general opinions on it.

Comment: not an answer on itself, but anandtech has a in depth analysis on it [here](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5057/the-bulldozer-aftermath-delving-even-deeper)

Answer (score 3):

> So, my question to those who use it, have you observed any noticeable
>   problem with it ?

There is a flaw in the design and how it handles a single thread.  This means you get less performance in a single thread then the previous generation of AMD processors and Intels current ( Ivy ) and ( Sandy ) bridges.

Based on your usage it should be fine.

AMD's next iteration of processors will be in the form of a APU that based on reports should address some of the design issues in Bulldozer.  The first release will be mobile chips, after that APU desktop line, the CPU line release date is not known ( at least to me ).

The mobile APU release date is by the end of the summer.  Both AMD and Intel have delayed their most recent releases though.

Comment: If 'less performance' on a single thread is not much worse than ..say.. 15% deterioration from the Phenom 6 core processors, I'm fine with it. I'll look into some benchmarks to see if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Several people, me included, use to have problems running certain Steam games (Portal 2 in my case). The game would start, freeze, then cause a BSOD.

In most people's cases, the solution was to update the BIOS. For my motherboard, it took about 10 BIOS revisions before Portal 2 became playable.

Here's a link to one of the Steam forum threads about it.
http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2178085

Other than that, I haven't encountered any problems with it.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer. Your problems don't seem to be caused by the CPU but more of your overal system. A CPU normally is not the reason a program crashes.  A BSOD also indicates a DRIVER problem!

Comment: @Ramhound This was actually a [cpu compatibility problem](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/STEAMGamesonAMDFXplatforms.aspx). It's also mentioned [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldozer_(microarchitecture)#cite_ref-43).